# Does GridGain support auto discovery on Amazon EC2?

Tags: gridgain

I am new for GridGain and please correct me if I make any mistake. I am wondering if GridGain supports any auto discovery on Amazon EC2, which means the only thing I need to do is configuring something in the configuration file instead of implementing any SPI.

So far, I know I can make GridGain discover each nodes on Amazon EC2 via Static IP Based Discovery, implementation of  Disovery SPI or following the blog(http://blog.griddynamics.com/2008/07/gridgain-on-ec2.html). Do you have any easy way to deploy GirdGain on Amazone EC2?

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, GridGain supports discovery on Amazon EC2. Please take a look at [Amazon S3-based Discovery](http://doc.gridgain.org/wiki/display/GGN714/Automatic+Node+Discovery#AutomaticNodeDiscovery-AmazonS3BasedDiscovery).